# iCloud Two Factor Authorisation doesn't show code on trusted devices

Tags: icloud

I activated the Two Factor Authorisation at iCloud. Now, when I try to sign in at some Apple Service, I am getting the a message that a message was sent to my trusted devices with a code I have to enter.

But, nothing happened. Never. **I have to click on "Try again" and choose "Send Message to PHONE_NUMBER"**

After that, a message with the code gets send to my iPhone, I type in the number and it works.

But, nowhere the code is getting displayed. Neither on my Mac or my iPhone. It just works via Message.

Comment: I have same problems, two devices are listed in Devices of iClouds, and have message "This device is trusted and can receive Apple ID verfication codes). But both don't show verification code popup. I must get verification code from text message or get verification code manually. This problem has occurred since yesterday. (It's can due to I reinstall iphone and macbook). I tried remove devices, and signin again, but it still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a view things you should check:

1) Are both devices marked as 'trusted' in [icloud.com](http://icloud.com) (login, go to settings and see 'my devices'.

2) You have to be signed in with both devices with your iCloud account. Did you check both are correctly activated.